# What is the consequence of SPF error 'Too many lookups'?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I am adding a domain (xero.com) to our existing SPF record, to allow marketing emails to be sent from an external system and appear as if they are from us.

The SPF record for xero.com is large and including it would take our own SPF record over the 10 lookup limit, resulting in error `Permanent Error: Too many DNS lookup`

This is unfortunate, but what effect if any does this error actually have (for both hard and soft fail)?
Will it prevent any mail being sent, or allow all, or just ignore this included domain?

In addition to this, we advise some of our clients to include *our* domain in *their* SPF records so we can send mail on their behalf.

Could increasing the included domains on our SPF record have a negative impact on theirs?

Conversely, if I get round this problem by setting our SPF record to `v=spf1 +all` to allow everything, could this also have an undesired effect for our clients that might use our domain in their SPF record?

Comment: Give an example. To the best of my knowledge there isn’t a “include the other domain’s SPF record directive.” Instead you’re simply authorizing all the MX records of the other domain or the IP address of the other domain’s A record. So it doesn’t make any difference what your SPF record is for a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect is that your SPF record is ignored.  Please do the following. Your SPF record requires 6 lookups excluding any MX and A records included in the record.  (An MX record lookup may result in 2 or more lookups.)

- Use IPv4 or IPv6 addresses ranges in your SPF record not names.  This will prevent additional lookups.
- Don't include MX if you are providing IP addresses for the servers.
- You are using google as the MX, which is handled by the `include:_spf.google.com` entry.  You don't need the MX specification.

Consider setting up DMARC with a reporting address so you can determine if you could set a `-all` policy.  You will get reports on how well you are following your policy and failure rates.  Use a `report` disposition until the only failure reports you get are for email that does not originate from your domain. Don't set your SPF policy to `-all` until you are sure you have listed all the valid senders in your SPF record.

Comment: Note that it's possible that the SPF record would not be ignored. Example, the first IP address in the SPF record is unlikely to require 10 lookups to be found, and may authorize certain emails. Also: DMARC is a terrible way of determining if you can use -all if at all. Unless you're happy to have SPF-only receivers rejecting valid DKIM signed email that fails SPF, then you can't use -all. Since these are SPF-only receivers you can't use DMARC to see their rejections, they don't send reports you can parse.

Comment: @mc78 DMARC allows you to set the policy you want to use. The design recognizes the need to test policies before enforcing them.  Using a "report" disposition, won't change how the receiver deals the message. It has been my experience (based on reports) that most receivers will  accept the mail even if the stated disposition is "reject".   If a message with broken SPF is being rejected when the policy is "report", it would have been rejected anyway.  But DMARC lets you find out about those rejections.

Comment: if you're seeing DMARC aware receivers accepting email that fails DMARC and p=reject, then you're seeing either broken DMARC implementations or some shape of ARC implementation (that may be wrong or right). That said, neither Google, nor Yahoo, nor Hotmail will accept email that fails DMARC for domains where a p=reject policy applies. So your mileage may vary with quality of receiver implementation but for reasonable implementations you should eject p=reject to behave properly.

Comment: @BillThor are you saying if I am using "include:_spf.google.com" in my spf record, I don't need to add all of google mx records in my dns dashboard? eg: mx-> alt1.aspmx.l.google.com, mx-> alt2.aspmx.l.google.com, etc...

Comment: @koeder Exactly that is why they provide it.  It is how they present their SPF records. They also use IP address ranges to reduce the number of lookups required.

Answer (score 1):

Stop that right now! :)

1) never give customer's your SPF record for your marketing, Always use a subdomain.

`_spf.example.com` for example, are IP ranges you control and provide to customer's.

2) limit your exposure or remove SPF entirely. `+all` (in practice is likely ignored) says you authenticated all IP ranges, whereas `?all` is much safer.

3) marketing systems don't need your business email domain. If you're going to have multiple marketing backends you should have multiple subdomains. Typically they (ESPs) push for this, `sg.example.com` for sendgrid, `mg.example.com` for mailgun, etc...

4) remove redundant lookups, `a`and `mx` are likely addresses you know.

Comment: Probably an IT guy posted the question after receiving a request from finance team...not knowing what Xero is.  It is accounting/invoicing system and adding SPF record for xero will have 100% to do with invoice (PDF via email) delivery and nothing to do with marketing.  Xero still has broken SPF records (too many DNS lookups) in 2023.   You probably want your invoices coming from accounting@example.com or something like that I would suspect.

Answer (score 0):

The [SPF specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.6.4) requires that the number of mechanisms and modifiers that do DNS lookups must not exceed 10 per SPF check, including any lookups caused by the use of the "include" mechanism or the "redirect" modifier. Otherwise, an SPF PermError, more specifically "SPF PermError: too many DNS lookups", is returned.

The [**SPF PermError: too many DNS lookups**](https://dmarcly.com/blog/spf-permerror-too-many-dns-lookups-when-spf-record-exceeds-10-dns-lookup-limit) issue is interpreted by DMARC as fail. Therefore, when your SPF record falls foul of this limit, and DKIM also fails, your emails will fail DMARC authentication, which means your emails are not properly authenticated and might not reach the inbox.

I've created a blog post on this topic: [SPF PermError: too many DNS lookups](https://dmarcly.com/blog/spf-permerror-too-many-dns-lookups-when-spf-record-exceeds-10-dns-lookup-limit)